# Should we use observer methods to modify IBOutlet properties

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen code where IBOutlets modify their properties using a didSet like so..

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
 }
```

Is this considered good practice, or should we create a configure method in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Good question! But the answer is likely to be a matter of opinion — that is, I don’t see what criteria you could fairly use to accept one answer over another.

Comment: I like this approach because it encapsulates the configuration nicely: instead of filling `viewDidLoad` with a lot of miscellaneous stuff, the stuff involving the table view goes into the table view’s setter observer. However, it has its limitations and dangers; in `viewDidLoad` we can guarantee that _all_ outlets are configured, so they can refer to one another, but in an outlet setter observer we cannot guarantee that.

Comment: If the table view is an outlet connected in the storyboard, why not connect the data source and delegate in the storyboard as well? No need for code in this case.

Comment: Sorry -- yes this may be a matter of opinion, but I would like to hear people's thoughts on this matter. I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Comment: Well I think rmaddy's point here is quite germane. This is a valid technique but I think it is particularly appropriate for properties that cannot be set in the storyboard.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still think the question as posed is unanswerable. Is this a thing? Yes, clearly. Is it reasonable to do? Yes, clearly, at least sometimes. "Is this considered good practice"? Meaningless; now you're just taking a poll. I mean, yes, I do this sort of thing, but I would be hard pressed to answer a question involving about what good practice is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `didSet` here

```
outer part 
   didSet { 
     // refresh
  }
```

makes more sense if the outer var you observe is rapidly changing / real time so you need to react to this change , but for the current case which is the table is set only once from IB inner init using `didSet` has no bounce over putting the code inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes, there is no difference putting it in viewDidLoad vs in the didSet for IBOutlets. However, where do most professionals put it?

Comment: seeing some code in a tutorial doesn't make it a matter of judge , every developer do what he needs , personally i prefer it inside `viewDidLoad`  than `didSet` for the above reason which i think other people do also , when a developer sees `didSet` , it expects a RX action not 1 time action , so it's a miss lead

Answer (score 0):

usually I do this:

```
func setupTableView() {
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

So i call this method on my viewDidLoad()